# Use webpack dev server when running tests locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, livereload, webpacker

When I run my cucumber locally webpacker is compiling my packs:

> Webpacker is installed  
>   Using /path/to/config/webpacker.yml file for setting up webpack paths
>   [Webpacker] Compiling assets

Sometimes I want to open the debug console and see the test page in the browser. I type `current_url` and paste the output to the browser address bar. When I make changes in JS or CSS they are not visible when I reload the test page. But the changes are immediately picked up by the dev server

**How can I use webpack dev server instead of compiling when running tests locally? And it would be good to compile assets on CI. We use Solano and there is TDDIUM env variable**

I tried to set

`config.assets.compile = false` in config/environments/test.rb

but when I start the test I see the error:

> File with URL "/stylesheets/email.css"

We use sprockets alongside with webpacker.

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(
  email.css
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I found is add the following code to the test environment:

```
# config/environments/test.rb

# Use webpack dev server when running tests locally
unless ENV["TDDIUM"].present?
  ENV["NODE_ENV"] = "development"
end
```